# Can someone explain what evaluate() and dragAndDrop() are calling in the following Angular Test Code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, gridster

The following code is used to test the drag and drop orientation of an angular-Gridster application using Protractor.

I'm new to some of these function calls below, would someone be kind enough to explain the significance of evaluate() --the API definition is too confusing, and dragAndDrop()? -- can't find this function anywhere

```
describe('DragAndDrop Test', function () {

require('jasmine-expect');

beforeAll(function () {
    context = new Context();
    context.get();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

});

it('should drag and drop a tile', function () {

    //target is where we are dragging the box to.  Box is the Box
    var target = { x: 400, y: 400 };
    var box = element(by.css('.ng-scope.gridster-item'));

    //scope is going to hold the scope variables that tell us where the box is located
    //see the documentation for angular gridster on github for info on scope variable
    //get the standardItems Scope
    box.evaluate('standardItems').then(function (scope) {

        //make sure the box we are using is in column 0 and Row 0
        expect(scope[0].col).toEqual(0);
        expect(scope[0].row).toEqual(0);
    });

    //drag and drop the box somewhere else.
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(box, target).perform();
    browser.waitForAngular();

    //get the updated scope
    box.evaluate('standardItems').then(function (scope) {

        //test to see that the box was actually moved to column and row 2, better test
        expect(scope[0].col).toEqual(2);
        expect(scope[0].row).toEqual(2);
    });
    //this is to test the pixel location which is not the best
    box.getLocation().then(function (location) {
        expect(location.x).toEqual(476);
    });
});
});

var Context = function () {

//load the website
this.get = function () {
    browser.get('https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/main');
};
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) would evaluate expression in the scope of the element you call it on. Useful when you need to access a particular variable in the scope:

> Evaluates the input as if it were on the scope of the current element.

---

[`dragAndDrop()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_ActionSequence.html#dragAndDrop) is a "browser action" and is inherited from the `WebDriverJS` (remember, Protractor is built on top of `WebDriverJS`):

> Convenience function for performing a "drag and drop" manuever. The
>   target element may be moved to the location of another element, or by
>   an offset (in pixels).

Comment: thank you, could you explain evaluate() a little bit simpler?

Comment: @KunalOjha may I just refer you to the example usages and related threads - should clear things up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20620056/771848, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27629579/771848, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36385225/771848, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35946919/771848...